# Retrieve array and output results to generate a set of html images

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins

Simply put I'm using a plugin called magnific popup, which is a lightbox 
popup, and you can initialise it from a set of options on dom ready:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: [
        { src: "img-src.jpg"  },
        { src: "img-src2.jpg" },
        { src: "img-src3.jpg" },
        etc
    ]
});
```

I've created an array of images in javascript held within a div which then need to be passed into that list. Only I'm not sure how. Heres what I've got.

```
var $zoomurl = $('.gallery').find('img').attr('src');
```

How do I get the contents of var $zoomurl into items options? An explanation of the answer would be of value also!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$.map()`

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: $.map($(".gallery").find("img"), function(el) {
             return {"src":el.src}
           })

});
```

Comment: Thats worked! Thanks for your help. I have a slight problem with click event tho, it opens the gallery at the first image all the time. Theres an index selector that is accepted by magnific popup. Is there anyway of counting the items, 0 being the first entry, and using that to select the correct image?

Comment: `$.magnficPopup.open({ #items }, #index );`

Comment: @Aaron Not tried `$.magnificPopup` , though should be able to select item within `items` using `$.magnficPopup.open(items, 0)`

Comment: Yup, just not sure how to count the items with the above code and provide that index number. 
`$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: $.map($(".gallery").find("img"), function(el) {
        return {"src":el.src}
    })
}, #count ); `

Comment: @Aaron Could define array outside of plugin initialization, create variable to store `.length` of array , then initialize plugin. `var arr = $.map($(".gallery").find("img"), function(el) {
             return {"src":el.src}
           }); var len = arr.length; $.magnificPopup({open:arr}, len /* or, arr[0] */) `

Comment: Ive got a example of what I'm trying to achieve here: http://codepen.io/aaron-stez/pen/ZbxooO

Comment: hmm, no, the popup itself doesnt fire. What am I missing. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Hmm, well that works, however there'd be no need for setting the len var. Basically, when clicking the image within the slider the image popup should show the selected image, but this won't work as is currently. The index number needs to be a number and it needs to be relative to image the user clicks on.

Comment: Link to plugin documentation ?

Comment: @Aaron Could not locate portion of documentation where setting an index number is option as described at _"Theres an index selector that is accepted by magnific popup"_ ?

Comment: Sorry buddy, specifically I'm using a public method here afforded by magnific. http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#public-methods

Comment: So in the first example, there is a 0 to indicate which item it should open first. If this is set to 0 all the time, it will just open the first image. But i need it to change according to the order of the slider image the user clicks. Hopefully I'm explaining this correctly.

Comment: @Aaron Retrieve index of image at `click` event , set plugin option with index as last parameter ?

Comment: Thats correct, not quite sure how to achieve that though! < bit of a js noob

Comment: Done it! Don't need to retrieve the index, because flickity already has a cellIndex function which we can use to tell magnific what image to open! Its all working... thanks for your help @guest271314 :)